# Setting width of controlsFX dialogs

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, controlsfx

I'm using controlsFX for dialogs and I can't figure out how to set the width. A lot of my messages only include the title, masthead and buttons. But the text in the buttons isn't fully display. For example:

```
    Action deleteStuff = new DialogAction("Delete Stuff", ButtonBar.ButtonType.OTHER);
    Action deleteMoreStuff = new DialogAction("Delete More Stuff", ButtonBar.ButtonType.OTHER);

    Action response = Dialogs.create()
            .owner(stage)
            .title("Delete")
            .masthead("This is a delete dialog")
            .actions(deleteStuff,deleteMoreStuff,Dialog.ACTION_CANCEL)
            .showConfirm();
```

And one of the buttons will show: "Delete Mo..."

And yes, I know I should be using the Alert class, but the project is for machines running older versions of Java. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the target Java version is 7, you could try to use Alert from this backport: https://github.com/BertelSpA/openjfx-dialogs-jdk7

Comment: Thanks but the target is 8u25. It's a college project

Comment: Then you could try this other backport for java 8 before u40: https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/openjfx-dialogs.